# Javascript function to select images only works on first image

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a function I'm using to select photos. They become selected by being added to an array and having a green check mark placed over them. When they are clicked again, they should be removed from the array, and the check mark should be removed as well.

This works fine, except that if you select, then unselect a photo, it will not let you select it again after that. The only exception is the first photo in the list (top left) and I'm not sure why this is. You can select and unselect it as many times as you like and it works fine. I would like all photos to behave like this.

Here is my code:

```
var selectedPhotos = new Array();
function selectVehicle(photoID) {
    if ( selectedPhotos.indexOf(photoID) > -1 ) {
        $('#check'+photoID).css('z-index', '-1');
        selectedPhotos.splice(photoID, 1);
    } else {
        selectedPhotos.push(photoID);
        $('#check'+photoID).css('z-index', '1');
    }

}
```

You can view the page in action here:
http://lindseymotors.com/unassignedphotos.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the index of element to remove in [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) *Index at which to start changing the array*

```
var index = selectedPhotos.indexOf(photoID);
if(index > -1){
    selectedPhotos.splice(index , 1);
}
```

*Complete Code*

```
var selectedPhotos = new Array();
function selectVehicle(photoID) {
    var index = selectedPhotos.indexOf(photoID);
    if(index > -1){
        selectedPhotos.splice(index, 1);
        $('#check'+photoID).css('z-index', '-1');
    } else {
        selectedPhotos.push(photoID);
        $('#check'+photoID).css('z-index', '1');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide index of array as first argument to [splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) so, you can try this:

```
var selectedPhotos = new Array();
function selectVehicle(photoID) {
    if ( selectedPhotos.indexOf(photoID) > -1 ) {
        $('#check'+photoID).css('z-index', '-1');
        selectedPhotos.splice(selectedPhotos.indexOf(photoID), 1);
    } else {
        selectedPhotos.push(photoID);
        $('#check'+photoID).css('z-index', '1');
    }

}
```